# Invoke a SignalR hub from .net code as well as JavaScript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a SignalR hub, which i successfully call from JQuery.

```
public class UpdateNotification : Hub
{
    public void SendUpdate(DateTime timeStamp, string user, string entity, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.UpdateClients(timeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), user, entity, message);       
    }
}
```

update message sent successfully from JS like so

```
var updateNotification = $.connection.updateNotification;
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }).done(function () { });
updateNotification.server.sendUpdate(timeStamp, user, entity, message);
```

and received successfully like so

```
updateNotification.client.UpdateClients = function (timeStamp, user, entity, message) {
```

I can't work out how to call  sendUpdate from within my controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your controller, in the same application as the hub (rather than from elsewhere, as a .NET client), you make hub calls like this:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<UpdateNotification>();
hubContext.Clients.All.yourclientfunction(yourargs);
```

See **Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub** near the foot of https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

To call your custom method is a little different. Probably best to create a static method, which you can then use to call the hubContext, as the OP has here: [Server to client messages not going through with SignalR in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13648605/1014822)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example from SignalR [quickstart](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs)
You need to create a **hub proxy**.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Connect to the service
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/mysite");

        // Create a proxy to the chat service
        var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chat");

        // Print the message when it comes in
        chat.On("addMessage", message => Console.WriteLine(message));

        // Start the connection
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        string line = null;
        while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Send a message to the server
            chat.Invoke("Send", line).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```